# Difference between API and Rest Webservice

Tags: web-services, api, rest, service

When I go through different blogs and articles, the jargon on "REST service, API" put me in a bit confusion.

Can someone explain the difference between API and a  Rest service?

--
Regards
PT

Comment: API is an acronym for ``Application Programming Interface`` and provide computers integrate with services. ``RESTful`` Services are some special sort of an API.

Comment: You said "In short, a REST-service is some sort of API, an API is not a REST-webservice." Which means, API means something more than a REST Service. What is extra in API compared to a REST Service?

Answer (score 1):

In short, a REST-service is some sort of API, an API is not a REST-webservice.

Api stands for "Application Programming Interface", and means "A set of rules of how to interact between different pieces of code" A REST-service is a set of rules about how to interact between your code and some code out there on the internet.

Most times in real life, api or webapi is used for anything that provides a method of comunication between client (server) and server.